# Rails can't find Idenfity (ImageMagick) even though commandlines shows it's installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, imagemagick, centos

If I run `identify -version` no the command line I get:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.4-2 2012-01-04 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

But my rails app gives the following whenever I submit a form (which makes a thumbnail out of an uploaded image):

```
Could Not Run The `Identify` Command. Please Install ImageMagick.
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

This is what my `.bash_profile` has:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/:/usr/bin:$HOME/.rvm
export PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/imagemagick/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

My production.rb has the correct config for PaperClip as well:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

Comment: Just to check, what's the output of `which identify`?  Is it in `/usr/local/bin`?  From your `$PATH` it looks like it might be in `$HOME/local/imagemagick/bin`.

Comment: which identify gives `/usr/local/bin/identify`

Answer (score 1):

I think imagemagick is looking in Path, not PATH.
forget your .bash_profile, set it in your script:

```
ENV['Path'] = '/path/to/ImageMagick/bin'
```